# How to handle created contract instance on Remix

Tags: solidity, remix

I am writing some contract code by using Solidity on Remix.

[image]

As you can see, TreasureBox contract creates Gold contract and it calls take() method on Gold contract. But I can check that TreasureBox contract is deployed only even I executed profit() method. How to handle and check the contract created by originally executed contract ? Does anyone have an idea ?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Gold {
    bool public isTaken = false;

    function take() public {
        isTaken = true;
    }
}

contract TreasureBox {
    Gold g;

    constructor() public {
        g = new Gold();
    }

    function profit() public {
        g.take();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, If you want to know the address of the Gold contract just make `g` public.

Also, you can include another function in TreasureBox to read the variables in the Gold contract.

for instance:

```
function check_g() public view returns(bool){
    return g.isTaken()
}
```

So you can monitor what is going on in the instance of Gold created.

Hope this helps